how I remove shopname and shop url from the account migration form from dokan vendor registration?
I hide shopname and shop url on vendor registration form, but when on a customer dashboard the button "become a vendor" the form open it is not showing the fields because i hided it. but when I am submitting for become a vendor on account migration form, it show me error enter shop name and shop url. when i registration on myaccount page it is not showing this error as i hide it. but on migration form it is showing error.
i want this message is not show because i dont want to add shop name and shop url (https://i.sstatic.net/MRQkNCpB.png)

Hi @zubi-zia. Please provide more details about your question - the code with the problem and what you have already tried.

Please check this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-remove-shopname-and-shop-url-from-the-account-migration-form-from-dokan-vendor-registration/
